# How to round float in pandas with many zeros?

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

The Dataframe contains float numbers like 7.5600000000000005, 2.36599999999954.

I would like to change the numbers to 7.56 and 2.366.

Note that the number of decimal place is not fixed.

How to achieve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: On what condition the decimal precision is identified ?

Answer (score 0):

The pandas.DataFrame.round function could be used. Therefore, given a dataframe df -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([( 7.5600000000000005, 2.36599999999954)])
df.round(3)
```

The output rounded to the nearest thousandth will be -

```
7.56    2.366
```